# Autofill a textfield when clicking a value in jComboBox

Tags: java, sql, swing, jcombobox

Good evening all!

I've been working on a simple warehouse/inventory management system which is connected to a mySql database. One of the tables in that database (OESCODE) has information about which area ("AREA") of the warehouse an article is in, and a corresponding numeric value ("CODE"). Example, small goods would be 1, long goods would be 2 etc etc.

In the GUI, i've a jCombobox that allows you to select the area, and the idea is to have a textfield below display the corresponding numeric value.
Here's a screenshot of what I mean:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmfXR.png)

It's the fields labeled Hal (halCombo) and OES (oesTxt) Code. 
The corresponding code:

```
private void pickHalComboPopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {                                                              
    String fill = (String) halCombo.getSelectedItem();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM OESCODE WHERE AREA=?";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, fill);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            String code = rs.getString("CODE");
            oesTxt.setText(code);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Here's the catch though: the fields above (labeled Artiekelcode, Omschrijving and Eenheid) do EXACTLY the thing i'm describing above. Example, when i click a value in the Artiekelcode field, the Omschrijving and Eenheid fields get autofilled with the corresponding values (from a different database table, ofcourse).

Here's the code for that:

```
private void pickArticleComboPopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {                                                              
    String fill = (String) pickArticleCombo.getSelectedItem();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM STAMDATA WHERE ARTIKELNUMMER=?";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, fill);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            String desc = rs.getString("OMSCHRIJVING");
            String eenh = rs.getString("EENHEID");
            eenheidTxt.setText(eenh);
            pickDescriptionTxt.setText(desc);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

So for the past hours, I've been trying to figure out why it works on the fields above and not on the fields below, since both principles are the same.

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, it seems I've figured it out. It seems that the PopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible method was not being used, so I created it and called it again and it worked.

Comment: *"it seems I've figured it out."* Glad you got it sorted. For this question, one of two courses of action would be better than reporting success in a comment. 1) Enter a more complete answer below, then accept the answer when the site allows. 2) Delete the question with the link beneath the tags (towards the left).